# How can I programatically set login and trans_key for authorizenet payment method config?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-gateway, ce-1.9.2.2, authorize.net

I am trying to automate the config and deployment of a Magento 1.9 store. I have a load script that does everything I need it to except for configuring the authorize.net payment method's login and trans_key properties.

Here is a sample code block that configures everything except the credentials (123456 in this example):

```
// already have Mage
Mage::getConfig()
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/active', '1', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/payment_action', 'authorize_capture', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/login', '123456', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/merchant_email', 'me@home.com', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/title', 'Credit Card (Authorize.net)', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/trans_key', '123456', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/cgi_url', 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/cgi_url_td', 'https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/order_status', 'processing', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/test', '0', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/debug', '0', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/currency', 'USD', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/email_customer', '0', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/cctypes', 'AE,VI,MC,DI', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/allowspecific', '0', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/useccv', '0', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/min_order_total', '0', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/min_order_total', '0', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/sort_order', NULL, 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/allow_partial_authorization', '0', 'default', 0)
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/centinel', '0', 'default', 0);
```

Everything besides login and trans_key gets successfully set this way, but I need those fields to be set too.

How do I set the payment gateway credentials programatically assuming I have access to the Magento core API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both fields use `<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>`

If you take a look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Encrypted`, you can find:

```
/**
 * Encrypt value before saving
 *
 */
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    $value = (string)$this->getValue();
    // don't change value, if an obscured value came
    if (preg_match('/^\*+$/', $this->getValue())) {
        $value = $this->getOldValue();
    }
    if (!empty($value) && ($encrypted = Mage::helper('core')->encrypt($value))) {
        $this->setValue($encrypted);
    }
}
```

Please try this ... replace *(and same for `login`)*

```
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/trans_key', '123456', 'default', 0)
```

with

```
->saveConfig('payment/authorizenet/trans_key', Mage::helper('core')->encrypt('123456'), 'default', 0)
```

---

On load it will be decrypted via:

```
/**
 * Decrypt value after loading
 *
 */
protected function _afterLoad()
{
    $value = (string)$this->getValue();
    if (!empty($value) && ($decrypted = Mage::helper('core')->decrypt($value))) {
        $this->setValue($decrypted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution I was looking for, I figured it had something to do with encrypting it.